# about logical equivalence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

so the question is like this:
Define a new logical connective □ as p □ q ≡ p → ∼ q. Use the Laws of Logical Equivalence, the equivalence of → to a disjunction, and the definition of □ to show that
(p □ q) □ p ≡ p → q.

my question is that doesn't □ stands for → ∼ which means whatever is following the □ (lets say x) would eventually turn out to be sth like → ∼ x, so when applying the definition of □ to (p □ q) □ p, we just need to replace the □ with → ∼, and it turns out to be (p → ∼q) → ∼p, I am very confused because after applying the equivalence of → to disjunction and DeMorgan's law it eventually becomes p and q or ~p which is obviously not logically equivalent to p implies q, I have my steps as follows can anyone help me find out from which step am I wrong, thank you so much

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgDsG.jpg)

Comment: The steps seem correct: apply Distributivity to $(p \land q) \lor \sim p$ and compare with $p \to q \equiv \sim p \lor q$ (this is meant by the hint: "the equivalence of → to a disjunction")

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot some parenthesis in your hand written work. It is certainly the case that $(p \wedge q) \lor \sim p$ is equivalent to $p\to q$. We have,

$$(p \wedge q) \lor \sim p \equiv (p \lor \sim p) \wedge (q \lor \sim p) \equiv \sim p \lor q \equiv p\to q $$

Comment: oh now I see, I did forget the parenthesis at the last step, thanks for pointing that out